# Is it necessary to write a kernel-mode driver to monitor HTTP traffic?

Tags: windows, wfp

I'm writing a module for a download manager which monitors HTTP traffic and notifies main module when HTTP stream meets certain conditions.

Going through MSDN, I realize I have to use WFP. So I create a project and write a module that installs my provider and add a callout. Everything is working great until I find out that I have to use `FwpsCalloutRegister0` which is defined in `Fwpsk.h`. Including `Fwpsk.h` gives a *header not found* error because it's a header available in WDK which means `FwpsCalloutRegister0` is a kernel-mode function. So I can't use it in a user-mode application, right?

I know that writing a driver is difficult for the first time. Is there any other approaches that can solve my problem or do I have to write a driver?

P.S `LSP`  isn't what I'm looking for because it's deprecated.

**Update:**

There are other download managers that offer a solution for this problem. For example `Internet Download Manager` and `Free Download Manager`. I don't know what their approaches are.

Comment: Look at Fiddler and FiddlerCore.

Comment: Fiddler uses proxy. You cannot force every application to use a certain proxy so I can't go for this kind of approach. Take a look at these download managers: `IDM`, `FDM`. I want similar results.